# SocketIO duplicate events with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I've ran into issues in the past wherein SocketIO will emit duplicate events when using AngularJS. There are two common reasons as to why this occurs:

- Creating your event listeners inside the `connect` event listener.
- Event listeners being dynamically created multiple times (usual case with AngularJS).

Luckily, there are two common solutions that match with the above scenarios. Please see the accepted answer to understand these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating your event listeners inside the `connect` event listener**

This bug occurs if you create listeners inside your `connect` event listener. Simply move  these listeners outside the `connect` event listener.

Before:

```
socket.on('connection', _ => {
    console.log('Connected');

    socket.on('someOtherEvent', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

After:

```
socket.on('connection', _ => {
    console.log('Connected');
});

socket.on('someOtherEvent', data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Event listeners being dynamically created multiple times (usual case with AngularJS).**

This is a common problem if you register your event listeners inside a controller. To fix this, edit your service like so:

```
angular.module('socketIO', []).factory('socket', $rootScope => {
    class SocketHandler {
        constructor(url) {
            this._socket = false;
            this._url = url;
            this._events = {};

            this._build();
        }

        _build() {
            // Change for your configuration options below.
            this._socket = io.connect(this._URL);
        }

        on(event, callback) {
            if(this._events.hasOwnProperty(event))
                return this._events[event];

            return this._events[event] = this._socket.on(event, (...args) => {
                $rootScope.$apply(_ => {
                    callback.apply(this._socket, args);
                });
            });
        }

        emit(event, data, callback = false) {
            return this._socket.emit(event, data, (...args) => {
                if(!callback)
                    return;

                $rootScope.$apply(_ => {
                    callback.apply(this._socket, args);
                });
            });
        }
    }

    return { build: SocketHandler };
});
```

You can then use this in your constructor:

```
angular.module('someController', socketIO => {
    const socket = socketIO.build('your socket url');
});
```

The reason this fix works is because when you switch pages in AngularJS (with the default router) it recreates an instance of the controller. This means that multiple event listeners are now bound to a single event. We prevent this from occurring by caching our event listeners in `SocketHandler._events`, and returning the cached listener if we have it cached.